# Conditions in truffle migration

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration

How can I arrange conditional branching in truffle migration based on the chosen of the network for migration(development, ropsten, main, etc) or based on the Linux environment variables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The signature of the migration script function is:

```
module.exports = function (deployer, network, accounts) {
    ...
}
```

If you want to branch depending on which network you are, you can check the network parameter.

If you wish to use environment variables, you can access these via `process.env.<VARIABLE>`.